# Improving Maplex placement when ArcMap callouts cluttered

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, maplex, callout

I use ArcMap 10.2 to produce map document containing a lot of label boxes with line callout. Sometimes, I have so many labels that leaders come very matted. Then I use Illustrator to unravel.

[image]

Is it possible to tune Maplex to prevent leaders from superposing labels?

Unfortunately I can't reduce the size of boxes (graphic charter) neither its content. And I need the data exhaustivity.

Here are my Maplex parameters:

- View unplaced labels
- Placement quality to best
- The red, gray and black lines label weight ranking to 1000
- Leader tolerance = 0
- Regular placement
- Label offset = 15 mm with secondary offset between 15 mm and 200 mm
- Label buffer to 0%
- Background label and 'Never remove' options unchecked

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by @hornbydd](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156763/improving-maplex-placement-when-arcmap-callouts-cluttered?noredirect=1#comment231796_156763):

> I think the problem with leader lines crossing the text is not
> solvable, it was being discussed [[at
> Geonet]](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/99552) back in 2012.

There [an Esri staff member](https://community.esri.com/thread/99552#comment-275643) said:

> Unfortunately this is a recurring problem which we have patched a
> number of times, but have been unable to completely resolve. A fairly
> substantial rewrite is required to fix it and hopefully we will be in
> a position to do this soon.

If you have not already done so, I suggest seeing whether ArcGIS Pro may be able to produce a better result because ArcMap was "rewritten" to create that 20 years newer ArcGIS Desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to convert these labels to geodatabase annotations. This will create an Annotation Feature Class as a separate layer in your table of contents.

Then you can re-adjust them as needed. It's very tedious but you will get better results.

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-text/converting-labels-to-annotation.htm